Typescript mismatch of properties
I have an interface
export interface Report {
      date: Date | null;
      compName: string | null;
      count: number | null;
      id: number | null;
   }

And I am using it in a promise function like this
async getUserData(): Promise<Report> {
    return this.prisma.user.findMany({});
  }


But I get a typescript error saying Type '(GetResult<{ date: Date |
null; compName: string | null; count: number | null; id: number; },
unknown> & {})[]' is missing the following properties from type
'Report': date, compName, count, id ts(2739).

What am I doing wrong with this typescript error

I think you need Promise<Report[]> as the return type, as you're using findMany.

Does this question depend on prisma? Then please tag it such. Otherwise please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without reliance on third-party code.

It seems like this.prisma.user.findMany is already typed.  It doesn't feel like you need the explicit return type for getUserData
